# Is possible to reset jquery image upload plugin without refresh

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery multi file uploader by HayaGeek.

```
var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
             url:"PHP File...",
             fileName:"userFile",
             dragDrop:false,
             multiple:false,
             showFileCounter:false,
             allowedTypes:"jpg,jpeg,png,mov,mp4",
             acceptFiles:"video/*,image/*",
             showQueueDiv: "fileprogress",
             maxFileSize: 512000000,
             autoSubmit: false,

             onSelect:function(files)
            {

                $('#fileprogress').show();
                var filename = files[0].name;

                var valid_extensionsVideo = /(\.mov|\.mp4)$/;   

                if(valid_extensionsVideo.test(filename)){

                    uploadObj.startUpload();
                    $('#fileprogress').show();                  
                    }

                    else{

            var preview = document.querySelector('#imagepreview');


            var file = files[0];
            var reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", function () { 
            preview.src = reader.result;
            var canvasImageReady= $('#imagepreview').attr('src');

             CANVAS_IMG = canvasImageReady;
             set_my_image(CANVAS_IMG);

            $('#modalurl')[0].click();   
            }, false);

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }

                    }


             //to allow file submission.
        uploadObj.reset();

        return true;
            },
```

By default i have changed autoSubmit to false, so when i choose image file, it will not be uploaded just show in popup and i am using another method which upload image file to server. So everything working fine but when i upload video,instead of video i selected, it uploads all images which i selected before.

Is there is any way to  reset uploadFile after every file selected?

Like:

```
files = ""; or something else
```

I tried reset() function but still not working, reset function just reset progress bar.

There is another issue when i choose video first nothing happens just file upload bar visible and when i re select video again uploading work, but again with old images which i only select to view in pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I just added 2 functions after image uploading:

```
        uploadObj.cancelAll();
        uploadObj.reset();
```

By using CancelAll, It's reset all pending files. As Reset used to reset progress bars